# Can I fetch a webpage through a hidden service?

Tags: onion-services

The TOR documentation is not clear to me. Say I have a hidden service with a `.onion` address, can I use this service to fetch a webpage?

**Update**

To clarify my question, I have installed the Tor openshift [cartridge](https://github.com/xkollar/tor-openshift). It has generated a `.onion` address for the hidden service. I was wondering whether I could use this hidden service to fetch a page online anonymously.

I have created a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30681050/how-to-connect-to-hidden-service-from-node-js-using-socks4a) on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

A hidden service can be, but it is not limited to, a web service. A .onion site is much like any .com or .net .org site, can provide the same capabilities. The only difference is that .onion domains can only be reached through the Tor network, while they enjoy the privacy and the anonymity that Tor provides.

Comment: Thanks for your answer so far. I have updated my question to make it more precise.